# Apache / httpd not creating a PID file on boot

Tags: linux, service, chkconfig

I installed Subversion Edge 5.2.2 which uses Apache on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511. I installed it as a service which I can stop / start.

The `httpd.conf` has entry

```
PidFile "/opt/csvn-5.2.2/data/run/httpd.pid"
```

I configured the service to automatically start on boot but this seems to work differently from manual `sudo service csvn-httpd start` `stop`.

When the service starts on (re)boot **no** pid file `/opt/csvn-5.2.2/data/run/httpd.pid` is created!

This is rather unexpected. Ideally we would be able to configure services to automatically start on boot easily but as it turns out this requires some extra magic to work well.

What is the correct way to make services start on boot? What is the secret?

Comment: The documentation you are following is incorrect. For example CentOS 7 no longer uses the `service` command. Make you wonder what else may be incorrect to.

Comment: too...  But Subversion Edge is a standard product which installs without problems...and `sudo service csvn-httpd start` does work! The service also starts on boot. The only issue is that boot does not create the PID file.

Comment: @user430214 Actually the `service` command still remains in RHEL/CentOS 7 but as a wrapper for `systemctl` for backwards compatibility with existing System V init scripts that haven't been converted to systemd unit files ...

Comment: Which misses the point @HBruijn, if something as simple as that is out of date then what's to stop more important stuff being out of date.